# SpannableStringBuilder.insert() does not insert span if span of that type already present in the destination

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestringbuilder

I have 2 SpannableStringBuilders, sbDest and sbSrc.

I want to insert sbSrc into sbDest:

sbDest.insert(0, sbSrc)

That works - and sbDest ends up with the spans it had before the insertion plus the ones that are present in sbSrc.

However, if sbSrc contains a span of a type that is already present in sbDest, that span is not inserted.

The cause seems to be code under this comment in SpannableStringBuilder.java:

> // Add span only if this object is not yet used as a span in this
>   string

Anyone know why this behaviour, and whether there's a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question...

I was obtaining sbSrc from sbDest in the first place (to implement copy/paste functionality) using

SpannableStringBuilder ssbSrc = new SpannableStringBuilder(ssbDest.subSequence(start, end));

subSequence() does indeed copy the spans, but it doesn't clone them, so ssbSrc ends up with the SAME spans (same object instances, not just same types) as those in ssbDest...and that is why sbDest.insert() doesn't insert them.